# How function unless works int the example in Chapter 5 Higher-Order Functions from the Eloquent JavaScript 3rd edition?

Tags: javascript

## The function repeat seems to take n = 0 as the argument and I don't know why. Can someone explain it to me, please?

```
function unless(test, then) {
  
       if (!test) then();
}

repeat(3, n => {
  
     unless(n % 2 == 1, () => {
    
          console.log(n, "is even");
      });
});
```

// → 0 is even

// → 2 is even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing two arguments to function unless one is `Boolean` and another is `function`

```
unless(n % 2 == 1, () => {

          console.log(n, "is even");
});
```

Here  `n % 2 == 1` is first argument and `() =>  console.log(n, "is even"); }` is second

and in your function unless

```
function unless(test, then) {

       if (!test) then();
}
```

We are first checking the  if the test is false than only run the function passed as argument

Comment: I understand that passing n = 3 to the boolean argument in the unless function will produce True  so it won't  go to the second argument(the function) . What I don't understand is how many times the function repeat runs and what is the value of n when it first run.

Comment: So, unless n % 2 == 1, the test fails? And only if it fails, then() runs? Am I asking or phrasing this question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that the function repeat was predefined before in the chapter.

```
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}

repeat(3, console.log);
// → 0
// → 1
// → 2
```

That is why it starts with n = 0 because in the loop i is initialised to 0 and the function is evaluated as long i is less than n.